# The state machine consumer does not receive the azure service bus queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, masstransit, .net-7.0

I have 2 web apps (.net 7, both are hosted in Azure App Service) and Azure Service Bus (contain some queues, with this example being `order-start` and `order-member-start` queues)

1 web app (`web API`) hosts APIs:

- API `create order` go with queue `order-start`
- API `create order for member` go with queue `order-member-start`

(both APIs **send message** to queues **successfully**, and queues store messages on it)

1 web app (`web worker`) hosts consumers (implement based on Masstransit Saga State Machine)

*Version: MassTransit 8.0.12, MassTransit.AspNetCore 7.3.1, MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core 8.0.12*

`web worker`: **OrderForMemberState.cs**

```
public class OrderForMemberState : SagaStateMachineInstance
{
    public Guid EventId { get; set; }
}
```

`web worker`: **OrderForMemberStateMachine.cs**

```
public class OrderForMemberStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<OrderForMemberState>
{
    public OrderForMemberStateMachine(ILogger<OrderForMemberStateMachine> logger)
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        Event(() => MessageStarted, x => x.CorrelateById(x => x.Message.EventId)
            .SelectId(c => c.Message.EventId));
        //... other state configure eventIds

        Initially(
            When(MessageStarted)
                .Then(x =>
                {
                    x.Saga.EventId = x.Message.EventId;
                    x.Saga.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
                })
                .Then(x => logger.LogInformation("Message Order Started: " + x.Message.EventId))
                .TransitionTo(Started)
                .Publish(c => new ProcessOrderEvent()) // publish to other events....
        );

        //...Other states and events declaration

        SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
    }
}
```

`web worker`: **OrderForMemberStateMachineDefinition.cs**

```
public class OrderForMemberStateMachineDefinition : SagaDefinition<OrderForMemberState>
{
    public OrderForMemberStateMachineDefinition()
    {
        Endpoint(e =>
        {
            e.Name = "order-member-start";
            e.ConcurrentMessageLimit = 16;
        });
    }

    protected override void ConfigureSaga(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator,
        ISagaConfigurator<OrderForMemberState> sagaConfigurator)
    {
        if (endpointConfigurator is IServiceBusEndpointConfigurator sbc)
        {
            sbc.RequiresSession = true;
            sbc.LockDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); // 5 mins
            sbc.MaxAutoRenewDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            sbc.SessionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); // 5 secs
        }

        endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Intervals(30));
        endpointConfigurator.UseDelayedRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)));
    }
}
```

the same implements for others such as ***OrderStateMachine***, ...

`web worker`: **Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Host.MyMassTransitConfig(x =>
{
    // ... other consumers, state machines...
    x.AddSagaStateMachine<OrderForMemberStateMachine, OrderForMemberState,
        OrderForMemberStateMachineDefinition>().MessageSessionRepository();

    // Observers
    x.AddEventObserver<OrderForMemberState, OrderForMemberEventObserver>();
    x.AddStateObserver<OrderForMemberState, OrderForMemberStateObserver>();

    x.AddSendObserver<SendObserver>();

    x.AddPublishObserver<PublishObserver>();

    x.AddReceiveObserver<ReceiveObserver>();

    x.AddConsumeObserver<ConsumeObserver>();
});

var app = builder.Build();

await app.MyAppRunAsync();

static T MyMassTransitConfig<T>(this T builder, Action<IBusRegistrationConfigurator>? configureMassTransit = null) where T : IHostBuilder
{
    builder.UseMassTransit((hostContext, configurator) =>
    {
        configurator.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
        configurator.AddServiceBusMessageScheduler();
        configureMassTransit?.Invoke(configurator);
        configurator.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
        {
            using var scope = context.CreateScope();
            var options = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EventBusOptions>>();

            var endpoint = new Uri($"sb://my-test.servicebus.windows.net");

            cfg.Host(endpoint);

            cfg.UseTimeout(timeoutConfigurator =>
            {
                timeoutConfigurator.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
            });
            cfg.PrefetchCount = 100;
            cfg.LockDuration = "0:05:00";
            cfg.MaxConcurrentCalls = 100;
            cfg.MaxDeliveryCount = 5;
            cfg.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromDays(7);
            cfg.AutoStart = true;
            cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();
            cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);

            cfg.Publish<OrderForMemberStartEvent>();
            cfg.Send<OrderForMemberStartEvent>(s => s.UseSessionIdFormatter(c => c.Message.EventId.ToString("D")));
        });
    });
}
```

**Issue**

The above code is work, works so well and stable (it goes live one year), but recently (2 times a month) one issue has occurred:

At the first time, the `OrderStateMachine` can not receive or consume any message from the queue `order-start`

And at the second time, the `OrderForMemberStateMachine` can not receive or consume any message from the queue `order-member-start` (current)

Notice that:

- The Azure App Service which hosted the `web worker` is alive, and healthy, and other consumers, state machines in its work normally, receive and consume messages from other queues normally. Not see any problem with it
- The Azure Service Bus is alive and healthy, run check health for queue `order-member-start` is healthy and ready. Check other queues are the same status healthy and ready. Not see any problem with it.
- Messages stored in the queue are **active messages** (do not go to dead-letter), and all of the messages have **delivery count is 0**
- Not found any logs describing the reason why The `OrderForMemberStateMachine` can not receive or consume any message from the queue `order-member-start`

**My assumptions**

I assume that the connection between the `OrderForMemberStateMachine` and the queue `order-member-start` is lost, so the state machine can not recognize that in queue have messages to consume, and the queue can not know the destination (`OrderForMemberStateMachine`) to delivery messages

Or
The `OrderForMemberStateMachine` state machine/consumer is going down (but other consumers hosted in the same App Service are live and can work normally) so it does not receive the messages from the queue

(*I met this situation one time, and the issue was solved by restarting the App Service `web worker`, so maybe after restart, the connection is established again or the consumer is re-started and goes live again*)

But I am not sure of my assumptions, there are no logs or no notification or no signal for my assumption, just like the connection is lost or the consumer is down and they do nothing. (come and go without any trace)

I don't know what way to investigate, reproduce, and fix this issue.
Please give me your thoughts. Is that my configuration right? Is that I missing some config? or is it that I missed some observations so that I can not catch any logs related to this issue?

Comment: Upgrade to 8.1, also, remove MassTransit.AspNetCore, it's obsolete and I'm honestly surprised it compiled. All MassTransit packages should _always_ be the same version. If there isn't a current matching version, it's obsolete.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Should I add more observations or is that any wrong with my current configuration?

Comment: Logs, logs, logs. Up the level to DEBUG if needed.

Comment: Sure, will be up to DEBUG if can't find any info. I already added pipeline observers and state machines observers, is it good if I add lifetime observers, Can the ReceiveEndpointObserver check whether the consumers in the app are healthy or not?

Comment: After upgrade version, today, this issue occurs again, do you have any idea?

Comment: No clue, if you have a support agreement, you can [contact support](https://masstransit.io/support).